# How do I complete this tolerancing problem? Can someone walk me through Part 1?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, cad, tolerance

[image: I have been trying to solve this using rules of Basic hole and Basic shaft calculations but I keep getting it wrong.]
I have been trying to solve this using rules of Basic hole and Basic shaft calculations but I keep getting it wrong

Comment: For homework questions we ask that you show your work so far and where you are stuck. As your question stands it looks like you are asking us to do your homework for you.

Comment: Start by figuring out what it means.  What does an ANSI Preferred English Limits and Fits have to say about an RC4 classed fit?